# Should I set ARITHABORT in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking at some code that was written a while ago, in the database helper before a stored procedure is called they set `ARITHABORT ON`.

From my understanding this is not needed for versions of SQL Server later than 2005, if the ANSI_Warnings is ON.

Do I still need to set this ? Does it provide a performance benefit?

Edit 1 : According to [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) article I do not need to set it, but I can not find another definite answer on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [SET ARITHABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), setting ANSI_WARNINGS to ON will automatically set ARITHABORT to ON as well with a compatibility level at 90 or higher (SQL Server 2005 or above):

> Setting ANSI_WARNINGS to ON implicitly sets ARITHABORT to ON when the database compatibility level is set to 90 or higher. If the database compatibility level is set to 80 or earlier, the ARITHABORT option must be explicitly set to ON.

With compatibility level 80 you have to manually set it.

This is also possible that your software set it to off when it opens a connection and the only solution was to add it to the procedure.

After upgrading to compatibility level 90 or higher, you should run:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

If will remove execution plan and recompile procedures.

It can be good to also run both commands before new plans get created:

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(db_name);
EXEC sp_updatestats;
```

I assume this database might be old (SQL Server 2000 or earlier) and it may be good to run this as well:

```
DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY;
```

[DBCC CHECKDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064(v=sql.120).aspx) will check the DB and its data(types) used and make sure everything is fine with your new version and compatibility level.

Answer (score 0):

In our database we had some SPs running **much** faster with this, even on later SQL Servers.

This occurs, if your database is older and was pushed through times with upgrade scripts. In former days the default was not "ON" and therefore older databases might still work with a bad default.

Comment: Is there anyway to identify issues like this, so that I can fix them ? I would prefer not to have to set it on every query for the sake of a few old ones

Comment: @Captain0 You might check the settings of your db (section "Options"). In one of our older projects we chose a way to set these options generically on every call done from the application.